# assoc strings in doseq result in empty map

Tags: dictionary, clojure

I am learning Clojure by solving problems, I'm stuck [with one of them](http://www.coderloop.com/puzzles/topfive), basically I have to find the top five strings in a log file.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
(ns topfive
  (:import (java.io BufferedReader FileReader)))


(defn extract-query [line]
  (.substring line (+ (.lastIndexOf line "=") 1) (.lastIndexOf line "]")))

(defn process-file [file-name, queries]
  (with-open [rdr (BufferedReader. (FileReader. file-name))]
    (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
      (assoc queries (extract-query line) (inc (get queries (extract-query line) 0))))))

(process-file "in" {})
```

My problem is that `queries` does not contain anything, I've already checked that `extract-queries` returns the string I want, I thought that this might have something to do with the language itself, [I've read](http://clojure.org/functional_programming#Functional%20Programming--Immutable%20Data%20Structures) that Clojure has immutability at language level, but this still does not seem a good point to me.

Could you suggest something about what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clojure does have immutability at a low level, and hash-maps are immutable.  So `assoc` doesn't mutate a map in-place, it creates a new map with an updated item in it, and returns the new map.  You're calling `assoc` over and over, but discarding the results.

One fix is to use `reduce` instead of `doseq`.  `doseq` iterates over a seq and does something to each item, but doesn't accumulate any results.  So it should be used mostly for things that have side effects, e.g. printing to screen or file.  `reduce` similarly iterates over a seq, but it does accumulate results.

```
(defn process-file [file-name, queries]
  (with-open [rdr (BufferedReader. (FileReader. file-name))]
    (reduce (fn [queries, line]
              (assoc queries (extract-query line) (inc (get queries (extract-query line) 0))))
            queries
            (line-seq rdr))))
```

You could do a few things to simplify this a bit further.  There's no need for a `queries` parameter to `process-file`, since it's always going to be an empty map to begin with.  Your `assoc` line can be written more concisely using `update-in` and `fnil`; this also lets us avoid calling `extract-query` twice per line.  You can replace all the calls to the Java Reader classes with the Clojure wrapper `reader` in `clojure.java.io`.  You can replace your calls to `substring` with a regular expression; regex is more concise, but for large inputs your version might perform faster.  You could also replace the anonymous function in my example with a sugary reader macro version using `#()`, though it's starting to look a bit noisy at this point, so I'd probably use `let` to make it read a bit better.

```
(ns topfive
  (:require [clojure.java [io :as io]]))

(defn extract-query [line]
  (nth (re-find #"query=([^]]+)" line) 1))

(defn process-file [file-name]
  (with-open [rdr (io/reader file-name)]
    (reduce #(let [search-term (extract-query %2)]
               (update-in %1 [search-term] (fnil inc 0)))
            {}
            (line-seq rdr))))
```

Comment: One could also leverage built-in functions: `(frequencies (map extract-query (line-seq rdr)))`

Comment: Thank you very much Brian, you provided a lot of interesting points to think about. @Justin: I'll try that, thank to you too.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to Brians excellent answer: The threading macro may improve readability:

```
(ns stackoverflow
  (:use [clojure.string :only [split]]
        [clojure.java.io  :only [reader]]))

(->> (reader "input.txt")
     (line-seq)
     (map #(last (split % #"=")))
     (frequencies))
```